# Storing a list in SQL within Xamarin

Tags: android, database, list, sqlite, xamarin

I have a custom class that I've created for a User object. Within this user object it has a property that's a List. When trying to store it within the SQLite database on my app it says it doesn't support storing Lists. Is there any way to be able to permanently store Lists of generic types in Xamarin so when a user logs in they can see the list associated with their account? Code below.

User class.

```
    public class User
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Unique]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string AuthToken { get; set; }
        public List<HabytItem> Habyts { get; set; } //Want to store this list in a database.
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Lists are usually stored in databases as one-to-many or many-to-many relations, which require multiple tables. See https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/

Comment: @Jason Yes I've seen the extension but everytime I try to click on the readme it fails so I've been unable to read any documentation on it and thus haven't been able to even try implementing it.

Comment: google "xamarin sqlite extensions" for examples

Answer (score 1):

You can open the `readme documentation` in the previous version here: [sqlite-net-extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/ab867aaafc86631f9479558f4faf0b1d581f057b/), there has an example that shows you how to store a list in SQL with `SQLite-Net Extensions` version:

With SQLite-Net extensions, no more need to write the queries manually, just specify the relationships in the entities:

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

There are also `Read and write operations` in the document you can refer.